# basic understandig about kerberos sso in apache

Tags: apache-2.4, kerberos, single-sign-on

I'm trying to configure kerberos sso in apache at the moment.
On the test server the website **sub.internal.local** workes quite well in reference to the kerb sso.
When I try to adopt the config to another apache server, which is opend via **sub.external.com** I only get a log in dialogue.

So just for my understanding, what do I need to change in the krb5.conf file or the generating of the *.keytab file?

**internal.local is our internal active directory domain;**

external.com is our default webaddress from the outside, which also works internally because of an internal DNS-lookup zone;

Answer (score 0):

You have not explained that you went through the basic setup for SPNEGO here, so I'll assume you didn't.

- Did you create a principal for `HTTP/sub.external.com` in the KDC?
- Are you able to obtain a service ticket for `HTTP/sub.external.com` using either MIT's `kvno` or Windows `klist`?
- Did you update the keytab on the webserver with the extra principal's keys?
- Have you used a tool like `curl` to run the SPNEGO auth and read the logs?
- Did you configure the browser to allow SPNEGO at `*.external.com` (or whatever domain whitelist is appropriate)?
- Have you confirmed that the browser does actually perform a Kerberos exchange by readings its logs or at least checking if a ticket for the HTTP principal is fetched?
- Have you read the server side logs?